# changing static link to relative link

Tags: php, urls, links

I have self hosted my wordpress today, but I realised it is still having static link of my local installation, since now I am opening using my IP (as i haven't done DDNS yet) i want that link should change to IP followed by ret of the URL instead of static local url.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want links on your site to dynamically change depending on the domain name of the environment you're in?

To do this you can replace any hard coded links with the [`home_url()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/).

So you would change references to links from `http://192.168.0.1/your/path/here` 
to `<?php home_url(/your/path/here); ?>`

If your links were defined through the Wordpress Admin UI then you'll need to use filters or change all the links via an option in Settings. Refer to this question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014167/general-wordpress-link-filter

Answer (score 0):

I am happy that i would suggest you with some strategies so that you may find which one is useful and make use of it as per the scenarios that you are pertaining to it.

**Solution One:**

Bit Easier with the help of the plugin in WordPress.

Plugin Name: Relative URL

Plugin URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/

Description: Relative URL applies `wp_make_link_relative` function to links to convert them to relative URLs.

**Solution Two:**

How to Make Internal Links Relative in WordPress

Reference: I have found out a very easy and worth example so that you can follow it up and you can make the static links to relative on the fly.

https://www.webhostinghero.com/how-to-make-all-internal-links-relative-in-wordpress/

**Solution Three:**

An another Stack Overflow Answer that is found very useful when using relative URL is as follows:

Question: Relative URLs in WordPress

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187437/relative-urls-in-wordpress

**Solution Four:**

Another Informative posts that i have found to be is the below link and it is very much superb in order to make the relative URLS.

Reference: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2012/06/relative-urls.html

Hope so any of the methods will be useful and you may crack the hindrance that you have using these four methods on the fly.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to simple set your web server IP in wp-config.php like this:

```
define('RELOCATE',true);
define('WP_HOME','https://11.22.33.44');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://11.22.33.44');
```

And try if you don't have the web server problem.

```
curl -I https://11.22.33.44
```

and if you access the

```
curl -I http://11.22.33.44
```

is it forwarding properly...

> Important! Leaving the RELOCATE constant in your wp-config.php file is insecure, as it allows an attacker to change your site URL to anything they want in some configurations. Always remove the RELOCATE line from wp-config.php after you're done.

***Resouce https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL***

Comment: That's what I did but from dashboard

Comment: try from the wp-config

Comment: Thanks I will try that, but under general in dashboard it allows updating WP HOME and WP SITEURL.

Comment: OK check also the http:// protocol selector, else you can throw WordPress away and goto with the pelican :)

Comment: I have already configured it to use https signed using OpenSSL

Comment: OK, then use https:// and check your /etc/hosts file is set property, and also what is the output of curl -I https://11.22.33.44

Comment: What will curl -l 11.22.33.44 do ?

Comment: Aks, I will update the question because I cannot put the protocol inside these comments... it is filtered.

Comment: this is all I can help you in here, for other questions hit the 'Ask Question' button, sorry.

Comment: adding the define variables you mentioned, works in a way if I open and an not logged in it goes by local IP, but since Site address is supposed to be the IP people should be getting through is public ip, so when I locally from my browser hit login it takes me to that public ip and stays on public ip , I was expecting that hitting login would also keep me on local ip if accessing on my local network.

Comment: OK, but can you ask another question. Looks that you have some foundation with this quest achieved.